# Is it possible to customize Chatter component, such as dialogbox size?

Tags: chatter, iframe

I put my Chatter in iframe to prevent conflict with Bootstrap.But I have fixed size for iframe size to display Chatter.The issue here, when I click Show All component in Chatter,the dialog box is too big and does not fit iframe container.

[image]

Can we customize the dialogbox size?If possible,it also fit mobile size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find their class name and can apply your custom css. This is a type of hack so i don't know for how much time it will work. But its a quick solution and it will solve your problem.

> For Inspect Element in chrome: Right Click > Inspect element.

And to fit in mobile size apply css to your iframe and Chatter component will adjust itself. Hope it helps you

Comment: Seem like no way out, especially when I attached Chatter in bootstrap page.